# How to use Join and count inside LINQ to Entity Select tag {}?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to use this below query,

```
 var device = (from u in db.Employe
               where u.CardID != null && u.Department.Contains("IT")
               select new
               {
                   Id = u.ID,
                   TotalComputers = (from co in db.EmployeComputer 
                                     join dv in db.Employe on co.DeviceID equals dv.ID 
                                     where dv.Department.Contains("IT") 
                                     select co.CardID.Count()),
               })
              .ToList();
```

I am trying to get all the computers exist in IT department above query giving error,

> System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057
> Message=DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a
> collection ResultType. Parameter name: input   Source=   StackTrace: < Cannot evaluate the exception
> stack trace>

This error is coming on `TotalComputers` line

Can any one tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: It looks like you have a relationship between Employe and EmployeComputer. Could you use the navigation properties to resolve the computers?
Like `db.Employes.Where(e => e.Department.Countains("IT")).Select(e => new { id= e.ID, cnt = e.EmployeComputers.Count() })`

Comment: @Greg no i dont have relationship between these tables :(

Comment: Maybe like this: `db.Employes.Where(e => e.Department.Countains("IT")).Join(db.EmployeComputer, emp => emp.ID, comp => comp.DeviceID, (emp, comp) => new {emp, comp}).GroupBy(joint => joint.emp).Select(grp => new { id= grp.Key.ID, cnt = grp.Count() })` so you get rid of the subselect. Maybe you could use a `where` clause instead the `join` in your subselect.

Comment: The `join` looks strange to me too. I'd have expected the computer to have a property like `OwnerID`?